# segue to detailed tableview controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, segue

I am passing data from one view controller to another. The first view controller has a collectionviewcell, and the controller I am segueing to has a tableviewcell. When I click on the cell of the collection view which is also clicking on a user, I want to segue into a detailed view controller that has a list of all the post the user made (which is stored in firebase)

Here is what I have so far: -This is my controller with the collectionviewcell

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

  var posts = NSMutableArray()
  var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
  var loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

loadData()

}

  func loadData(){
        if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil{
     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                let loggedInUserData = snapshot
                if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for post in postsDictionary {
                        self.posts.add(post.value)
                    }
                    self.CollectionView.reloadData()


                }})}
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "details" {


   if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {

            if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath{
                let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
                let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let posted = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [NSMutableArray: AnyObject]
                let username = post["username"] as? String
                let userpicuid = post["uid"] as? String
                let userpostuid = post["uid"] as? NSMutableArray
                vc.username = username
                vc.userpicuid = userpicuid
                vc.posts = posts
                print(indexPath.row)
            }
        }}
```

Right now when I click on the cells I segue into the detailed view controller and it displays all the posts made by all the users in my database and I know it is because in my segue I write `vc.posts = posts`. I am new to swift and I don't know how I will set it up so that when I click a cell (which is also when I click a user) then a detailed tableviewcontroller shows me all the post, only that user has made

Again, I am trying to only display the post uploaded by indiviual users

Comment: Filter posts by the relevant user selected and set it to the detailed view controller. Do this in `prepareForSegue`. To filter use `let filteredPosts = posts.filter.filter { $0.user == userSelected }`

Comment: @user1046037 will userSelected be the uid?

Comment: That was just an example use what ever filter condition is relevant. In your case probably it would be $0["username"] == "abc". In this case the sure selected has the username "abc". It is an example

Comment: @user1046037 I tried that but I don't think I am doing it correctly, sorry I am new to swift.  I have updated my post to include my database, can you please help

Comment: Is this a collection view that displays a list of posts or does it display a list of users ?

Comment: The collectionview in the first view controller displays a list of users. Well technically I have a button within the collectionviewcells that displays the pictures of the users and the actual cells display the post. But the button is what I am seguing with @user1046037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview:

- A collection view displays a list of posts.
- Each cell represents a post.
- Each cell has a button with the user image when tapped on it, the app segues into `UsersProfileViewController`.
- `UsersProfileViewController` contains a property `posts` which represents the posts made by the user.

## Question:

- How to set the `UsersProfileViewController` in such a way that it displays only the posts made by the selected user ?

## Approach:

- Each cell is dequeued and is reused.
- When a button is tapped it needs to know which index path the button corresponds to.
- Once the indexPath of the cell containing the button is known then we can determine the user associated with it.
- Once the user is known filter the posts based on the selected user.

## Steps:

1. Create a subclass of button with indexPath as a property
2. Use that custom button in your cell
3. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` set the button indexPath
4. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` set the target for the button
5. When the button is pressed, determine the corresponding username and store it as `selectedUserName` (view controller property).
6. In `prepareForSegue` filter posts based on the `selectedUserName`

## Sample Code:

```
class CellButton : UIButton {

    var indexPath : IndexPath?
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    let post = posts[indexPath.row] as? [String : Any]

    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.titleLabel.text = post?["title"] as? String
    cell.button.setTitle(post?["username"] as? String, for: .normal)
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedOnUserButton(button:)),
                          for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.button.indexPath = indexPath

    return cell
}

@objc private func tappedOnUserButton(button: CellButton) {

    guard let indexPath = button.indexPath else {
        return
    }

    print("button pressed - \(indexPath)")

    let post = posts[indexPath.row] as? [String : Any]

    selectedUserName = post?["username"] as? String
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {


        //Filter posts based on username
        //Assumption: posts contains all the posts.
        let postsForUser = posts.filter {

            guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else {
                return false
            }

            return post["username"] as? String == selectedUserName
        }

        print("postForUser = \(postsForUser)")

    }
}
```

## Preferred Approach:

- Create a `struct` called `User` (instead of using a dictionary, which is error prone while coding)
- Create a `struct` called `Post`, Post would have a property called User to map the user - https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11
- Please learn `Swift`, each language has some features that you can take advantage of.
- Don't force unwrap variables unless you are 100% sure it would contain a non-nil value
- Use native types whenever possible (example use Swift Array instead of `NSMutableArray`)
- Please explain your question clearly so that others don't have to spend time trying hard to understand. (Be precise and clear and isolate the problem, and use markdown for formatting)

Comment: I get an error on `let postsForUser = posts.filter { $0["username"] == selectedUserName }` under the $0. it says "cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type"

Comment: `let postsForUser = posts.filter {
                guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else {
                    return false
                }
                return post["username"] as? String == selectedUserName
            }`

Comment: Use the above mentioned filter. This error was caused because you are using `NSMutableArray`, swift is strongly typed you should consider using native types (swift array, swift dictionary), you could have avoided this error completely.

Comment: im really sorry to keep bothering you but whenever I have `let post = posts[indexPath.row]` then I get an error on `selectedUserName = post["username"]` that "Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: `let post = posts[indexPath.row] as? [String : Any]` and then `selectedUserName = post?["username"] as? String`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. The last one worked

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help a couple months ago. I just recently updated to the new xcode and prior to updating this like `vc.posts = (postsForUser as! NSMutableArray)` worked perfectly but now it causes the app to crash. I am still very unfamiliar with the new xcode and I am not sure why it is crashing

Comment: Try to use native Swift Array instead of `NSMutableArray`. Learning the language might help you understand better. If you must use `NSMutableArray`, then use it like `NSMutableArray(array: postsForUser)`

Comment: Please take the time to learn the language, that might help you in the long run otherwise you might end up not understanding how things work. The Swift language book on iBooks is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup segue from collectionViewController to tableViewController in your storyboard, then give it an identifier (very important).

In your collectionViewController, override `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? YourTableViewControllerClassName {
        // assign data you want to pass here
    }
}
```

Then in your `collectionView:didSelectItemAt` method, call `performSegueWithIdentifier("yourID", sender: self)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I already have this information and it is included in my original post. That is not the problem I am having, the problem is in the post. If it is not clear, I can reword my post